# How do I delete ALL collections for a project in Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I can delete one at a time within the console, but there is no option to delete multiple/all, and I've accidentally created about 100 collections for a single project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a Cloud Function, as explained in the doc: [Delete data with a Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

> Once you deploy this function, you can call it directly from your
> mobile app or website to recursively delete documents and collections.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! @Renaud Tarnec

For anybody else, I used the following command line command:

```
firebase firestore:delete --all-collections
```